# What does it mean density function $f(x) = dF(x)$ (in distributional sense)?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

It is known that the probability density function $f(x)$ and the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ are related as $f(x) = \frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x}$. 
However I am confused why at some places the density function is written as just $dF(x)$.

This came up in the definition of Stieltjes Transform: $m(z) = \int \frac{1}{x - z} dF(x)$. And it is mentioned that

> The density function  $f(x) := dF(x)$ in the distributional sense

Is this just the issue with notation or is there specific reason to write the density function as $dF(x)$?

Comment: There may not be an everywhere defined density function.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Differentiation

Comment: In this instance, it is sort of short for $\frac{dF(x)}{dx} dx$ - that is, the integral is really: $\int \frac{f(x)}{x-z} dx$, but they are writing $f(x)dx = dF(x)$ as a shorthand notation and, perhaps, for clarity.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok. Does the term 'in distributional sense' have any specific meaning? I have also seen 'distributional derivative' term being used. Do these terms mean something?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Like atomic density functions?

Comment: Yes, presumably the integral is the Stieltjes integral.

Comment: It's a Stieltjes integral wrt $F(x)$ and $dF(x)=f(x)$ in the sense that if a density $f$ with respect to some dominating measure $\mu$ exists then $\int g(x) \ dF(x) = \int g(x) f(x) \ \mu(dx)$ meaning that if one side of this equation is defined then so is the other and they are equal. I probably would have wrote $dF(x) = f(x) \ \mu(dx)$ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a notation thing.  Maybe like the notation for a [differential operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator).

Comment: This should have been a comment.